# adding a marker at the end of an animated line chart - D3.JS

Tags: d3.js

I am working on an animated line chart and I just want to add a marker at the end of path. I am fairly new to d3.js and I am stuck at this point.

Comment: It would greatly help if you could create a [mre] of your code, preferably in a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). That way, we can more easily answer your question and you'll be more likely to get a good answer!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.